# Async wait on file descriptor using Boost Asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, dbus

I'm trying to integrate D-Bus with my `boost::asio` application.

D-Bus has an API that enumerates a set of Unix file descriptors (mainly sockets but could also be FIFOs) to be watched.
When those descriptors have something to be read I should inform the D-Bus API so it can read them and do it's thing.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
using boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor;
void read_handle(stream_descriptor* desc, const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                 std::size_t bytes_read)
{
    if (!ec) {
        stream_descriptor::bytes_readable command(true);
        descriptor->io_control(command);
        std::size_t bytes_readable = command.get();
        std::cout << "It thinks I should read" << bytes_readable
            << " bytes" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "There was an error" << std::endl;
    }
}

void watch_descriptor(boost::asio::io_service& ios, int file_descriptor)
{
    // Create the asio representation of the descriptor
    stream_descriptor* desc = new stream_descriptor(ios);
    desc->assign(file_descriptor);

    // Try to read 0 bytes just to be informed that there is something to be read
    std::vector<char> buffer(0);
    desc->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, 0),
        boost::bind(read_handle, desc, _1, _2));
}
```

But the handler is called right away saying that it has 0 bytes to be read. I would like it to be called only when there is something to be read, but boost::asio **CAN NOT** read it. It should act just as a glorified `select()`. Is there a simple way to do that?

PS: I'm extensively using `boost::asio` in my software, this is just a small part of it, so I would like not to depend on `glib` or other mainloops.

Comment: What is the D-Bus API that you're using? Is it the low-level C API?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is precisely the problem [null_buffers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html) was [designed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) for.

> Sometimes a program must be integrated
>   with a third-party library that wants
>   to perform the I/O operations itself.
>   To facilitate this, Boost.Asio
>   includes a null_buffers type that can
>   be used with both read and write
>   operations. A null_buffers operation
>   doesn't return until the I/O object is
>   "ready" to perform the operation.
>
> As an example, to perform a
>   non-blocking read something like the
>   following may be used:

```
ip::tcp::socket socket(my_io_service);
...
ip::tcp::socket::non_blocking nb(true);
socket.io_control(nb);
...
socket.async_read_some(null_buffers(), read_handler);
...
void read_handler(boost::system::error_code ec)
{
  if (!ec)
  {
    std::vector<char> buf(socket.available());
    socket.read_some(buffer(buf));
  }
}
```

There's also an [excellent example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/nonblocking/third_party_lib.cpp) included in the documentation.

Comment: This was just what I was looking for. It integrated perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Sam, can you explain more about the excellent example included in the documentation you mentioned?  I want to use the `third_party_lib.session` to Read/AsyncRead/Write/AsyncWrite something, how can I do it?  I'm still not so clear.  The example simulating the third_party_lib confused me actually. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter please ask a new question, include what part of the example you find confusing.

Comment: @Sam, I have posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235055/how-to-apply-this-boost-asio-example-to-my-application  Please check it out.  Thanks.

Comment: I was using async_read_some with libcurl in this manner, but had a problem where it returns without an error when the server closes the socket, and the boost/asio socket also still thought it was open. I used async_receive instead with the message_peek flag and a buffer of size 1 to detect the EOF.