# 0MQ, Boost.Asio, and Windows

Tags: windows, boost-asio, zeromq

I have been following the excellent advice on using 0MQ and Boost.Asio on a POSIX-ish platform (MacOS) at [Using ZeroMQ together with Boost::ASIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829005/using-zeromq-together-with-boostasio).  Unfortunately, though, I am writing code which needs to work on both POSIX-ish and Windows.  I'm not having much luck, so far, with my attempts to translate this advice to the Windows side.  I can't seem to figure out how to match the type returned by getsockopt(ZMQ_FD) on Windows and what I think should be the Windows equivalents of boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor.  Here is what I've tried:

```
zmq::context_t zenv(1);
zmq::socket_t zocket(zenv, ZMQ_PUSH);
SOCKET zfd;
std::size_t zfd_size = sizeof(zfd);
zocket.getsockopt(ZMQ_FD, &zfd, &zfd_size);
boost::asio::io_service ios;
boost::asio::windows::stream_handle io(ios, zfd);
```

And the error I get when I try to compile it.

```
2>Z:\zee-zmq-socket.cpp(14): error C2664: 'boost::asio::windows::basic_stream_handle<>::basic_stream_handle(boost::asio::io_service &,void *const &)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'SOCKET' to 'void *const &'
2>          Reason: cannot convert from 'SOCKET' to 'void *const '
2>          Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

So far, my Google-fu has been weak; I can only seem to find examples which deal with Boost.Asio and 0MQ on POSIX-ish.  I'm not sure what I need to do to correctly get from a SOCKET to a `void * const`.  The closest advice that I've been able to find is about combining 0MQ and libcurl: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/5071.  And this advice also makes me nervous that my compilation problems are only the tip of a much nastier iceberg hiding under the surface.  In particular,

> The reason why there is a assign, but no release-function for 
>   boost::asio::ip::tcp::sockets is that once a socket is "bound" to a completion 
>   port you cannot "unbound" it or "bound" it to another completion-port.

And so I'm worried there might be other gotchas about which I might not know and which would not even be so polite as to manifest themselves as compile-time errors.  Thank you in advance for any help.