# Select functionality in boost::asio

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I am going to use boost::asio lib for my project. But it's not quite obvious which function is corresponding to `select()` from native socket C lib. Is that available in asio? Or does boost provide an alternative to find out if a socket is ready?

Comment: +1 this may seem like a basic question, but I've found new users to the asio library are often confused by this concept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The high-level design of `Boost.Asio` is based on the [Proactor desing pattern](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html). Thus, you don't need to poll on `select`. Instead, submit your completion handler for an asynchronous operation, and when the operation gets completed - the completion handler gets called.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation has a [specific section](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/bsd_sockets.html) for mapping the BSD socket API calls into their respective Asio equivalent

> **`poll()`, `select()`, `pselect()`**
>
> `io_service::run()`, `io_service::run_one()`, `io_service::poll()`,
>   `io_service::poll_one()`
>
> Note: in conjunction with asynchronous operations.

Note that there are subtle differences between each of these `io_service` methods, picking the correct one will depend on your application design.

Answer (score 5):

Boost.Asio does provide a select like functionality using null_buffers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4686523/1134207 explains more.