# Return a value from a thread in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

What's the **most efficient** way to return a value from a thread in C++11?

```
vector<thread> t(6);

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    t[i] = thread(do_c);

for(thread& t_now : t)
    t_now.join();

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    cout << /*the return of function do_c*/
```

Also, if the change will benefit performance, feel free to recommend another thread than `std::thread`.

Comment: Did you accidentally a word? Return a value from a thread, right?

Comment: ? what do you mean? yes

Comment: yes, but I want the most efficient way

Comment: I am looking for a low level wrapper not a high level one

Comment: Canonical ways to do this in C++11 are presented in the code example on cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future Those are high-level, but there is no reason to assume they aren't efficient.

Comment: If I am launching hundreds of threads, can I get them faster than std::thread?

Comment: When you say "the most efficient CPU-wise way", you mean "the method that is most efficient CPU-wise", right?

Comment: So how many different ways have you discovered so far?

Comment: boost thread, std::thread, async, future and posix thread

Comment: @luka - If you are launching 100's of threads there lies the performance problem. Having multiple threads only makes sense when you have enough processors and/or it makes sense in terms of easy program implementation. Otherwise you lose a lot of performance in context switching. Anyway joining threads do not have much of a performance overhead as the call gets blocked by the OS

Comment: yes, I know this but many threads make sense when you download stuff.

Comment: That doesn't sound like those threads would be CPU-bound.

Comment: many threads doesn't necessarily make sense when you download stuff.  it all depends on the specific scenario, and in all likelihood, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @luka - No it does not - There are other techniques. e.g. `select`

Comment: If I download stuff from a server and the server responds with limited speed e.g. 100kbps but my speed is pretty high eg 10mbps, I bet 1b$ the way to download as many stuff as possible in the shortest time possible, is with 100 threads.

Comment: @luka - Using select `will` not require context switches. Besides you dot have 1b$

Comment: :P when you say select you mean I must have database access to the server, right? If that's the case, I have to database access to the server.

Comment: I understand the drawback of context switching, but I believe I have no other option here. Because the CPU is pretty important and must be used for other tasks, I am looking to do this using as little CPU as possible.

Comment: @Luka - See http://linux.die.net/man/2/select - There is an equivalent for windows

Comment: somebody doesn't understand the difference between io bound and cpu bound here

Comment: Owh, I didn't know that about select, I will search it a bit...

Comment: i will take your bet for $1B.   seems the question was asked because the poster doesn't know about many things.  i/o vs cpu, socket api, etc.  i would close the question before more arguments ensue.

Comment: Threads are in general heavy.  Having significantly more threads than processors is rarely efficient.  Multiplex your downloads in one thread using `select` and use asychronous (non-blocking) io to save them out to disk.

Comment: `select` blocks (i.e. gets put in a `blocked` queue). When something blocks, it will not be scheduled until it has received an event (i.e. it won't use CPU at all).

Comment: aha, this seems great... when can I learn more about those blocks?

Comment: @luka - read the manual page that i gave the link to.

Comment: If I want to do this with boost::asio, how to do it? I mean, where in the boost doc is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422769/select-functionality-in-boostasio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lauching a thread and terminating it require many hundreds of machine cycles. But that's only a beginning. Context switches between threads, that are bound to happen if the threads are doing anything useful, will repeatedly consume even more many hundreds of machine cycles. The execution context of all these threads will consume many a byte of memory, which in turn will mess up many a line of cache, thus hindering the CPU efforts for yet another great deal of many hundreds of machine cycles.

As a matter of fact, doing anything with multitasking is a great consumer of many hundreds of machine cycles. Multitasking only becomes profitable in terms of ***CPU power usage*** when you manage to get enough processors working on lumps of data that are conceptually independent (so parallel processing won't threaten their integrity) and big enough to show a net gain compared with a monoprocessor version.

In all other cases, multitasking is inherently inefficient in all domains but one: ***reactivity***. A task can react very quickly and precisely to an external event, that ultimately comes from some external H/W component (be it the internal clock for timers or your WiFi/Ethernet controller for network traffic).

This ability to wait for external events without wasting CPU is what increases the overall CPU efficiency. And that's it.
In terms of other *performance* parameters (memory consumption, time wasted inside kernel calls, etc), *launching a new thread is **always a net loss***.

In a nutshell, the art of multitasking programming boils down to:

- identifying the external I/O flows you will have to handle
- taking reactivity requirements into account (remembering that more reactive = less CPU/memory efficient 99% of the time)
- setting up handlers for the required events with a reasonable efficiency/ease of maintenance compromise.

Multiprocessor architectures are adding a new level of complexity, since any program can now be seen as a process having a number of external CPUs at hand, that could be used as additional power sources. But your problem does not seem to have anything to do with that.

A measure of multitasking efficiency will ultimately depend on the number of **external events** a given program is expected to cope with simultaneously and within a given set of **reactivity limits**.

At last I come to your particular question.

To react to external events, launching a task each time a new twig or bit of dead insect has to be moved around the anthill is a very coarse and inefficient approach.

You have many powerful synchronization tools at your disposal, that will allow you to react to a bunch of asynchronous events from within a single task context with (near) optimal efficiency at (virtually) no cost.
Typically, blocking waits on multiple inputs, like for instance the unix-flavoured `select()` or Microsoft's `WaitForMultipleEvents()` counterpart.

Using these will give you a performance boost incomparably greater than the few dozen CPU cycles you could squeeze out of this task-result-gathering-optimization project of yours.

So my answer is: don't bother with optimizing thread setup at all. It's a non-issue.

Your time would be better spent rethinking your architecture so that a handful of well thought out threads could replace the hordes of useless CPU and memory hogs your current design would spawn.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, neko-san. It made me change my mind and decide not to use threads.

Comment: @Luka glad to have contributed to spare you (and your compiler and your CPUs) a lot of unnecessary suffering ;)

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted your post by mistake, please edit it to upvote it...

Answer (score 8):

First of all `std::thread` doesn't return a value, but the function that is passed to it on construction may very well do it.

There's no way to access the function's return value from the `std::thread` object unless you save it somehow after calling the function on the thread.

A simple solution would e.g. be to pass a *reference* to the thread and store the result in the memory pointed to by the reference. With threads though one must be careful not to introduce a *data race*.

Consider a simple function:

```
int func() {
    return 1;
}
```

And this example:

```
std::atomic<int> x{0}; // Use std::atomic to prevent data race.

std::thread t{[&x] {   // Simple lambda that captures a reference of x.
    x = func();        // Call function and assign return value.
}};

/* Do something while thread is running... */

t.join();

std::cout << "Value: " << x << std::endl;
```

Now, instead of dealing with this low level concurrency stuff yourself you can use the *Standard Library* as someone (as always) has already solved it for you. There's `std::packaged_task` and `std::future` which is designed to work with `std::thread` for this particular type of issue. They should also be **just as efficient** as the custom solution in most cases.

Here's an equivalent example using `std::packaged_task` and `std::future`:

```
std::packaged_task<int()> task{func}; // Create task using func.
auto future = task.get_future();      // Get the future object.

std::thread t{std::move(task)};       // std::packaged_task is move-only.

/* Do something while thread is running... */

t.join();

std::cout << "Value: " << future.get() << std::endl; // Get result atomically.
```

Don't always assume something is less efficient just because it is considered as "high level".

Comment: The question that springs to my mind is: what *functional* requirement would justify to use a mechanism designed with parallel processing of sizeable amounts of data in mind to retrieve a mere integer thread return value? Looks more like what I call a syntax-driven software design. These kind of solutions sit pretty as C++11 versatility showcases, but they ***do*** hide considerable resource consumption under an icing of syntactic sugar, IMHO.

Comment: @kuroineko It all depends on the domain i guess. For general purpose application development I would go with the standardized classes and functions for maximum understandability among coworkers, instead of custom solutions. Are there any functional requirements to justify using the abstractions? Well I can't think of any. But lacking a functional requirement to justify abstracting code for better maintainability doesn't make it less important. Non-functional requirements are also essential.

Comment: As I see it, it's a matter of finding a sweet spot between ease of use and wasteful, if not potentially dangerous habits. In that specific case, I think it's worth pondering a bit about the price of comfort. I did design embedded software for a decade or so, that's probably why seeing so much resources invested to avoid so little an effort tends to make me nervous :).