# Parallel downloads without threads

Tags: c++

I am trying to use boost asio in order to download 100 files in parallel, from a server with max speed 100kbps while my PC has 10mbps.

I decided against using threads due to the serious performance hit. I learned about `select` and `I/O Multiplexing`. I was pointed to this question: [select functionality in boost::asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422769) but the answer doesn't provide enough details.

In my application I use the `sync_client` example from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/client/sync_client.cpp).

Please explain how to download 100 files in parallel in boost asio without threads, with some kind of `select` mechanism?

Comment: Why would you do that? Downloading 100 files in parallel at 0.1 MB per second means that if the connection gets broken, none of the files will have finished. Why don't you just queue the 100 downloads, and download those files in smaller numbers instead?

Comment: I have permission from the server owner to do so many downloads. Also, I must download the files as fast as possible.

Comment: Are those files of tiny size to begin with?

Comment: Yes, very tiny (about 5kb)

Comment: When I say "as fast as possible" I mean, even 0.1 second slower matters.

Comment: 'I decided against using threads due to the serious performance hit' - what performance hit?

Comment: If one computer has 2, 4 or 8 cores and I start 100 threads I will really beat the crap out of it and make the CPU go 100%, not including context switching. I don't want the CPU go 100%, even for 1 second.

Comment: If the server capacity is 100 kbps then that's as fast as it gets. If you download 100 files simultaneously you'll get at most 1 kbps per download. And downloading small files over TCP/IP is extra slow because of the protocol.

Comment: No, the server capacity is much higher than 10mbps, but every connection is limited to 100kbps. Is there a fastest but equally secure protocol for HTTP downloads than TCP?

Comment: @Luka I have BitTorrent running now.  It is downloading stuff. It has 60 threads.  CPU use 1%.  100 network threads is, like, nothing.  OK, I would probably go with a pool of, say, 32, but only 'cos I have code for it already.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out... I will try to modify my threads code...

Comment: @Luka - Ooh, I didn't realise you already tried it with 100 threads.  If you tried with 100 threads and you got 100% CPU use, you're doing it wrong somehow:)

Comment: What's the fastest thread in c++, boost, std, posix?