# About create boost.asio async_xxxx handler object

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am reading Boost.Asio source code, but there is the code I am confused. Has anyone help to explain for better understand, or some materials I can refer for understanding?  Thanks.

The actual code:

```
// Wait until data can be received without blocking.
  template <typename Handler>
  void async_receive_from(implementation_type& impl,
      const null_buffers&, endpoint_type& sender_endpoint,
      socket_base::message_flags flags, Handler& handler)
  {
    bool is_continuation =
      boost_asio_handler_cont_helpers::is_continuation(handler);

    // Allocate and construct an operation to wrap the handler.
    typedef reactive_null_buffers_op<Handler> op;
    typename op::ptr p = { boost::asio::detail::addressof(handler),
      boost_asio_handler_alloc_helpers::allocate(
        sizeof(op), handler), 0 };
    p.p = new (p.v) op(handler);

    BOOST_ASIO_HANDLER_CREATION((p.p, "socket",
          &impl, "async_receive_from(null_buffers)"));

    // Reset endpoint since it can be given no sensible value at this time.
    sender_endpoint = endpoint_type();

    start_op(impl,
        (flags & socket_base::message_out_of_band)
          ? reactor::except_op : reactor::read_op,
        p.p, is_continuation, false, false);
    p.v = p.p = 0;
  }
```

especially for:

```
typedef reactive_null_buffers_op<Handler> op;
typename op::ptr p = { boost::asio::detail::addressof(handler),
  boost_asio_handler_alloc_helpers::allocate(
    sizeof(op), handler), 0 };
p.p = new (p.v) op(handler);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific -- which bit(s) don't you understand?

Comment: you need a Good IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm..lets see..you are trying to understand the function `async_receive_from` of `reactive_socket_service` class. Specifically the one which takes a `null_buffer`.

The signature of the function:

```
template <typename Handler>
  void async_receive_from(implementation_type& impl,
                          const null_buffers&, 
                          endpoint_type& sender_endpoint,
                          socket_base::message_flags flags, 
                          Handler& handler)
```

Now, what is the importance of the `null_buffers` ?

In brief, it basically allows one to do the buffer management in the invoked callback rather than providing the buffer while calling `async_receive_from` like in its other overload. 
 See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4686523/434233) answer for more detailed explanation for its use case.

What is `reactive_null_buffers_op<Handler> op` ?

Since you are at this point, I am assuming that you are aware of `operation` class in asio. In simple words, it basically invokes a user provided callback when the particular operation is executed completely. Look for `scheduler_operation::complete` in `scheduler_operation.hpp`.

`reactive_null_buffers_op` is derived from `scheduler_operation`(via `reactive_op`) and it also stores the copy of the Handler passed to `async_receive_from`. The actual details are bit more complicated and wieldy. For now it might be sufficient to know that the `do_complete` method of this class is what does the upcall to the handler.

What is `typename op::ptr` ?

Look for `ASIO_DEFINE_HANDLER_PTR` in `handler_alloc_helpers.hpp`. In simple terms, its a struct which holds the handler passed to the async function. ASIO needs to allocate the handler separately on heap (or via a custom allocator) to make sure its exists for the duration of completion of the socket receive operation. This is what below 2 lines does:

```
typename op::ptr p = { boost::asio::detail::addressof(handler),
      boost_asio_handler_alloc_helpers::allocate(
        sizeof(op), handler), 0 };
    p.p = new (p.v) op(handler);
```

We are creating an instance of `reactive_null_buffers_op<Handler>` on the allocated space via `placement new` (2nd line).

Now what ?

One ASIO has stored the user passed handler object, it needs to start the main read operation on the socket. For that, it calls the `start_op` function. The details of `start_op` is beyond the current scope of the asked question. So, in brief `start_op` ends up registering the socket to the poller, say `epoll`. And our handler, now in `op` ends up getting called when the read operation is ready to be performed (Lots of details skipped for that).

Comment: I think a correction is needed here:
"in brief start_op ends up registering the socket to the poller", now, by the time you call async_* the IO object on which it has been called (basically the descriptor ) has to be already registered , if not, it will be registered before Starting any OP, so the start_op basically registers the Handler; not the socket (or push the Handler ) to the op_queue associated with the IO object's descriptor_data.